# from OpenGLContext import testingcontext i cant import testingcontext

Tags: python, opengl, openglcontext

When i do this:

```
import OpenGLContext
```

its importing, there is no problem. But when i write

```
from OpenGLContext import testingcontext
```

its giving an error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import testingcontext
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OpenGLContext\testingcontext.py", line 10, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import plugins, context, contextdefinition
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OpenGLContext\context.py", line 33, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import texturecache,plugins
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OpenGLContext\texturecache.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext import atlas
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OpenGLContext\atlas.py", line 4, in <module>
    from OpenGLContext.arrays import zeros, array, dot, ArrayType
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OpenGLContext\arrays.py", line 2, in <module>
    from vrml.arrays import *
ImportError: No module named 'vrml'
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `vrml` phython module is missing. So the first step would be installing that.

Comment: Yes. I tried that. Then gave another name of  module in there. It was like "Phil".